# Are financial returns considered more volatile in recessionary times as opposed to expansionary times?

Tags: portfolio-management, market, mean-variance, financial

I need help in understanding some results that I have obtained.

I am doing some out-of-sample performance analysis for different targets of volatility in mean-variance optimization where I solely change the way the covariance matrix has been estimated. HC in the figure refers to the sample covariance matrix, whereas GS refers to the Gerber-Statistic based covariance matrix (see [here](https://blog.thinknewfound.com/2015/07/new-paper-markowitz-introducing-gerber-statistic/)) which is supposedly more robust to outliers and noise in the data.

Now, if we observe the below figures, one can see that the risk-adjusted-return (adjusted according to HC) for GS is generally lower in expansionary times while its much higher in recessionary times. Now, a plausible explanation for this is that GS works better under more volatile times influenced by noise and outliers. However, I can't find any theories that support the fact that returns are more volatile in recessionary times, compared to expansionary times. Do you have any ideas regarding this matter?

[image: Expansionary out-of-sample performance (evaluated during expansionary periods)]

[image: Recessionary out-of-sample performance (evaluated during recessionary periods)]

Comment: The 2015 Markowitz paper linked above, describing the Gerber Statistic based covariance matrix has been withdrawn from SSRN (2627803). A description of the method can be found in a Royal Inst. of Tech. thesis by Zakaria Marakbi http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1060405/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.princeton.edu/~yacine/leverage.pdf

> The leverage effect refers to the observed tendency of an asset’s
>   volatility to be negatively correlated with the asset’s returns.
>   Typically, rising asset prices are accompanied by declining
>   volatility, and vice versa. The term “leverage” refers to one possible
>   economic interpretation of this phenomenon, developed in Black (1976)
>   and Christie (1982): as asset prices decline, companies become
>   mechanically more leveraged since the relative value of their debt
>   rises relative to that of their equity. As a result, it is natural to
>   expect that their stock becomes riskier, hence more volatile.

Comment: It's implied by the skew too.